# On compactness of the space of probability measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, compactness

Let $X$ be a complete metric space, and denote by $\mathcal{P}(X)$ the set of probability measures on $X$. I am interested in proving that if $X$ is compact then $
\mathcal{P}(X)$ must be compact in the weak-* topology, which is induced by the convergence against $C_b(X)$, that is, the bounded continuous functions.

Since $\mathcal{P}(X) \subset (C_b(X))^*$, and the unit ball of $(C_b(X))^*$ is compact in the weak-* topology (by Banach-Alaoglu), all that is left to do is prove that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is weak-* closed. This should be easy, but I'm stuck: where does the compacity of $X$ come in? (The result is obviously false for non-compact $X$: consider a sequence of delta measures $\delta_{x_n}$ and $x_n \in \mathbb{R}, x_n \to \infty$.)

Answer (score 19):

The other answer is correct, but a little brief so I decided to add a few words.

Let's begin with the Riesz representation: For a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$,
 the map taking the finite signed regular Borel measure $\mu$ to the functional $f\mapsto \langle f,\mu\rangle:= \int f\,d\mu$ 
 is an isometric isomorphism of the Banach space $M_r(X)$ onto the dual of the 
Banach space $C_0(X)$. Here $C_0(X)$ is the space of continuous functions that vanish at infinity, 
and the norm on $M_r(X)$ is the total variation norm.

Now  Banach-Alaoglu guarantees that the unit ball in $C_0(X)^*$ is weak${}^*$ compact, which
corresponds to [vague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vague_topology) compactness for the measures. However, generally, 
the unit *sphere* in $C_0(X)^*$ is not weak${}^*$ closed and hence not compact. Note however that the 
cone $\cal P$ of positive elements in $M_r(X)$ is vaguely closed:
$${\cal P}=\bigcap_{f\in C_0(X)_+} \left\{\mu: \langle f,\mu\rangle \geq 0\right\},$$
so its intersection with the unit ball is compact.

The intuition here is that the *positive part* of the unit sphere is tiny, so 
 could well be compact even though the whole sphere itself is not.

So how does the compactness of $X$ enter into the picture? If $X$ is compact,
then $C_0(X)=C_b(X)$ and the vague and weak topologies of measures coincide. 
In particular,  the constant function "1" belongs to $C_0(X)$ so the space 
of probability measures is the compact set
$$ {\cal P}\cap \{\mu: \|\mu\|\leq 1\}\cap \{\mu: \langle 1,\mu\rangle =1\}.$$

Answer (score 8):

Use Riesz representation theorem. Suppose you have a weak-* limit. This is necessarily a positive functional on $C_0(X) = C_b(X)$, with norm $1$. So you're done.

Answer (score 1):

$\{\mu:⟨1,\mu⟩=1\}$

$P=\cap _{f\in C_{0}(X)} \{\mu:⟨f,\mu⟩≥0\}$

Those μ should not only be considered from $C_{0}(X)^*$
They are in the product topology space of $C_{0}(X)$ copies of R: the set of all real valued functions defined on $C_{0}(X)$. Then we can say the valuation at any $C_{0}(X)$ is continuous so the preimage of 1 will be closed.

Then by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, the {$\mu: \mu \in C_{0}(X)^*$ and ∥$\mu$∥≤1} is compact.
By the Rietz reprentation theorem, the norm for this signed measures space(functionals for continuous functions) is the total variation norm.

And $\{\mu: \mu \in C_{0}(X)^*$, ∥$\mu$∥≤1}$\cap\{\mu|\mu$ a real function on $C_{0}(X):⟨1,\mu⟩=1$} is already enough to tell the set of Probability Borel measures is weak-* closed/compact

If a signed measure is with full measure 1 and total variation full measure no more than 1, using Hahn-decomposition, it must be a positive measure with full measure 1 thus probability measure.